# Place Logo next to text in header

Tags: html, css, image

I'm attempting to place my logo right next to my text in the header of my webpage. I have played around with the 's but the best I can do is have the logo sit on top of the test. How can I fix this?

```
 <header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <img src="img/blue.png"><h1>WELCOME</h1>

            <p></p>
          </div>
 </header>

  <!-- CSS BEGINS -->
  header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    background-image: url();
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
 }

  header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
 }


  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: lowercase;
   font-weight: 700;
   color:gray;
  }
```

Comment: You can try using the CSS property `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float the image to the left with css:

```
.header-content-inner img {
  float: left;   
}
```

Here's a working fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/0ocu4pt8/

Comment: Thanks, that looks better. Is there a way to bring it closer to the text in the center?

Comment: Thank you - is there a reason this interacts with the size of the text in <h1>? It makes it significantly smaller.

Comment: The H1 was being displayed as "block", and in order to get it to collapse, I needed to add "inline-block".  The same effect can be acheived leaving the H1 as "block" and adding a left margin the width of the logo.

Answer (score 1):

By default, heading tags (h1-h6) use `display:block`, which means that they take up the entire width of their parent container. Instead, you could set your h1 to use `display: inline-block`. Which will then make it only take up the width it needs, so it can display on the same line as your image. So, your CSS rule would become:

```
  header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: lowercase;
   font-weight: 700;
   color:gray;
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could float the image to the left!

```
float: left;
```

^ Just add this to the image class.